# Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Inside a `XAML` Page I'm trying to use an `IValueConverter`, it's throwing an error.

- The `IValueConverter` is in another assembly, I have added a reference
- There are no design-time errors
- I have assigned the StaticResource with a ResourceKey

At the top of my page I have this:

`xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Converters;assembly=Converters"`

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/DialogStyles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <converters:NoWhiteSpaceConverter x:Key="NoWhiteSpaceConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```

Then I try to use it later on like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SomeText, Converter={StaticResource NoWhiteSpaceConverter}}" />
```

Can anyone see what the problem is?

Comment: @Sebastian, The error is the title of the question.

Comment: Can you put the resource into the App.xaml? Maybe you ran into a problem like this one: http://www.paulkiddie.com/2011/10/the-importance-of-the-position-of-window-resources-element-in-wpf-xaml-markup/

Comment: I'm having the same issue, reloading the designer seems to solve the issue untill you restart visual studio...

Comment: @DTex, No, not that this time, although that did fix something else yesterday.

Comment: @Sebastian, Thanks, this is working now. If you post as answer and I will mark.

Comment: @Sebastian Yes sorry i got it the other way around, i have a design time error but no error at runtime

Comment: Forgot to call `InitializeComponent()` somewhere?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Make sure that the resources are defined before the usage (in Xaml parsing order). The easiest way is to place it into App.xaml

See also here for a similar issue: https://paulkiddie.com/the-importance-of-the-position-of-window-resources-element-in-wpf-xaml-markup/

Comment: I define a converter in App.xaml and assign it a key. I get that exception when I reference the converter from a `UserControl` in the app.

Comment: The link does not work.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the resource was correctly defined before it is used but there was a wrong reference to a converter.

The problematic line was

```
...{Binding MyProperty, Converter={StaticResource local:MyConverter}}
```

and it should be without the namespace alias

```
...{Binding MyProperty, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}
```

where `local` is a namespace alias containig the converter class and `MyConverter` is the key defined in a resource in the XAML.