# Implementing own ViewModelLocator

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, viewmodellocator

I wanted to implement ViewModelLocator by my own. So I implemented the simplest app in the world. I did everything as in [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/20c06b/viewmodel-locator-in-wpf/) tutorial. But I'm still getting an exception:

> XamlParseException occured
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in
>   PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: 'Provide value on
>   'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.' Line
>   number '8' and line position '9'.

This is this line:

```
DataContext="{Binding MainWindowViewModel, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}">
```

Here is the code:

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="ViewModelLocatorDemo.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:viewModelLocatorDemo="clr-namespace:ViewModelLocatorDemo">
    <Application.Resources>
        <viewModelLocatorDemo:ViewModelLocator x:Key="ViewModelLocator"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
namespace ViewModelLocatorDemo
{
    using System.Windows;
    using ViewModelLocatorDemo.Views;

    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);

            MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
            mainWindow.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModelLocator.cs**

```
namespace ViewModelLocatorDemo
{
    using ViewModels;

    public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        public MainWindowViewModel MainWindowViewModel
        {
            get { return new MainWindowViewModel(); }
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="ViewModelLocatorDemo.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300"
        DataContext="{Binding MainWindowViewModel, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}">
    <Grid>
        <Frame x:Name="MainFrame" Margin="50" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
namespace ViewModelLocatorDemo.ViewModels
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        public string MainText { get; set; }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            MainText = "The first page";
        }
    }
}
```

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13866628/4945059) I found:

> Make sure that the resources are defined before the usage (in Xaml
>   parsing order). The easiest way is to place it into App.xaml

So I have it in App.xaml. If somebody would me explain what's going on here? Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are running into this bug [WPF - App.xaml file does not get parsed if my app does not set a StartupUri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543414/wpf-app-xaml-file-does-not-get-parsed-if-my-app-does-not-set-a-startupuri)

From that page:

> There's a VS code generation bug where the code necessary to connect  to the rest of the program sometimes is not inserted when  contains only one entry and does not have a StartupUri attribute.

From that page, there are 3 solutions (summarizing here for completeness):

- Add `x:Name="App"`
- Add more resources in App.xaml like `<viewModelLocatorDemo:ViewModelLocator x:Key="ViewModelLocator"/>` and `<viewModelLocatorDemo:ViewModelLocator x:Key="ViewModelLocator2"/>`
- Rather than overriding OnStartup, try using an event instead, `Startup="Application_Startup"`

This was definitely not obvious, and was difficult to troubleshoot and even find an answer for in my own search.  Hopefully *this* answer will help others find the *other* answer.